# Can I do something without intents or in some cases I am bound to use them?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, sms

Let's say I want to send SMS or Email. Do I have to use intent for this (which calls OS native service) or I can send SMs/Email/MMS/etc. from within the app? Is it possible to do this without opening OS native services/tools screen?

All material I found explain these tasks by using intents. I was wondering if I really have to rely on intents.

PS. I know that they are recommended way of dealing with things, but not mandatory. When I develop bar-code-scanning app, a client will not allow using external app (called via intent), but he'd like to do it all within the app. So why shouldn't I do the same with sms/email/mms/etc.?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SMS or Email you can of course invoke native methods that allow you send messages. These intents are just another option - if you don't want to create the sms/email sender activity yourself.
Sending sms:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a) out for sending email in the background.

Comment: So this will send sms message in the background without invoking the native sms screen that I usually get via intent?